# Sending email from Emacs, authinfo error: Unexpected ‘machine’ token at line 2

Tags: emacs, mu4e

I am managing multiple email accounts with mu4e.
Everything works fine expect sending emails: I am getting the following error

```
auth-source-netrc-parse-entries: auth-source-netrc-parse-entries: Unexpected ‘machine’ token at line 2
```

My `authinfo` file looks like this:

```
machine <...> login <...> port <...> password <...>
machine <...> login <...> port <...> password <...>
```

`smtpmail-smtp-server`, `smtpmail-smtp-service` and `smtpmail-smtp-user` are
all defined in my mu4e configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem temporarily, I created 2 files: `authinfo.gpg` and `authinfo2.gpg` for each email address and added the following line in the configuration:

```
(smtpmail-auth-credentials . (expand-file-name "/path/to/corresponding/authinfo.gpg"))
```